# Fitlering data by "destination-value" of a field

Tags: jquery

Open Graph should use this syntax:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the title" />
```

but some website use `name` instead of `property` (also stackoverflow, check it out this question html). And I've also seen other parameters, such as `data-og`.

So, I'd like to select/filter an element with jQuert that contains `og:title` as value instead of `property`, because this:

```
$mypage.filter("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content");
```

won't work for example if I parser a stackoverflow page (which has `meta name='og:title'`).

How can I do this in jQuery? Filter by "value-destination"? Tried with:

```
$mypage.filter("meta[*='og:title']").attr("content");
```

but it give to me fields that does not contains `og:title`

Comment: if I remind correctly, `*=` means "contains".. so I think the selector is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can use the multiple selector:

```
$('meta[property="og:title"], meta[name="og:title"]').first().attr('content');
```

And filter out the first object if there are multiple tags differing only in "name" or "property" attribute.

Comment: Yes, but what's about if someone use `data-og='og:title'`? It fails... since there is no standard in this web 2.0 :(

Comment: Just add that too... `$('meta[property="og:title"], meta[name="og:title"], meta[data-og="og:title"]').first()`. Provided you have a list of known possible attributes. Chances are there will ever be only one of these combinations. Even if someone uses all combinations (highly unlikely), then the `.first()` rescues you. **But yes**, if someone uses an entirely *random* attribute then you cannot account for them this way.